# Burn ISO file on virtual machine to real DVD

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image

I've a 3 gigabyte ISO file on my Ubuntu virtual machine on VirtualBox, and I would like to burn this file to a *real* DVD. I know that I can burn an ISO file to a DVD using right-clicking on the file and choosing "Write To Disc", but if I try that, my real DVD is not listed. How can I make sure that my real DVD is listed so I can burn the ISO file to it?

Comment: In the settings of the virtual machine did you add an entry for the DVD drive?

Comment: @cybernard: In VirtualBox, I went to the Storage settings of the Virtual Machine, but I'm not able to add a DVD.

Comment: @ProgramFOX - Does the virtual machine see the actual optical disk drive installed in your system?  Does your system support all required hardware virtualization?

Comment: @Ramhound: According to the Microsoft HAV Detection Tool, my computer is configured with hardware virtualization.

Comment: Why cant you copy it to host and burn? Much easier I believe.

Comment: @tumchaaditya: It is indeed easier, but I thought burning from guest would be faster than copying to host and then burning.

Comment: How is it easier to make an image, copy that to a host, and then burn it to the host when you should be able to directly burn it from the guest?  It's the 21st century, after all.

Answer (score 3):

Storage

1. Click on the SATA or IDE depending on your system
2. Click the **+** symbol to the right for add **CD/DVD**
3. Say leave empty
4. Click on the device labelled **Empty**
5. Goto the right side of the screen
6. Click the drop down next to the tiny CD icon and select your real CD/DVD drive letter.
   **Host Drive d:** for example.
7. Click passthrough
8. Click Ok

reboot the VM and try again.

Comment: Something strange: when I click "Write to disc", then I get a disc with 1.7 gigabyte free space, but I actually have more than 4GB free space on my disc. What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have the newest version of VirtualBox 4.3.6?  Did you start the virtual machine with the DVD already in the drive?

Comment: Yes, I have the newest version. About the DVD already in the drive, I'm not sure, but I'm not going to test it now. Currently I'm just trying to compress the ISO file to a .7z file and then uploading it to a website and downloading it again on my primary system.

Comment: Why upload it to a website?  If ubuntu(the guest OS) has **samba** installed you can go directly to the VM from the host.  Once **samba** is installed an configured.  On the host Run: **\\<ip address of guest\sharename**  Click Ok or <Enter>

Answer (score 0):

You do not need *passthrough* at all. Just grab the CD/DVD driver from the rim of your VM windows after starting it.

But there are also other solutions,  like writing your *iso* image to a folder shared between host and guest, and then use the host's instruments to burn the image to DVD.